# link to shared objects in custom location in Android platform

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have build a native C user space application using NDK (using BUILD_EXECUTABLE property in NDK).

My application consists of main program that uses few shared objects (shared libraries that I created using BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY).

I can run the application all right (I'm using LG-G4) BUT: **It only works if I copy the *.so files to both /system/lib and /system/lib64 on the phone.**

Is there a way to copy the *.so files to some custom location (say /data/my_dir) and that the application can still link to the *.so's in run time?

Comment: You don't need any special permission to `rwx` files located in `/data/local/tmp`. You might try, if the problem is still actual.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to answer, but anyway, this answer might be helpful for others who encounter such a problem. You don't have to copy *.so libraries from your native library directory to anywhere, just told the ProcessBuilder where your libraries are located something like this:

```
//your process builder which executes
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(argvlist);
//lbpath - path (your native dir) of shared libraries which are used by executable
pb.environment().put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", lbpath);
```